# Complete contours (outline) from a image

Tags: plotting, image-processing, image

I want to find the contours of (parts) image and sent the output to a laser cutter. For example, take this image:

[image]

I use this code:

```
maskv1 = AlphaChannel[RemoveBackground[bal1]];
 contours =  
 ImageMeasurements[   EdgeDetect[Blur[ImageMultiply[bal1, maskv1], 2],
 1], "Contours"]; bal4 = ImageGraphics[   ColorNegate[   
 DeleteSmallComponents[
     Dilation[
      EdgeDetect[BilateralFilter[Graphics[contours], 7, .1]], .6], 
     Method -> "Mean"]], ImageSize -> 600];
```

The output is:

[image]

The red line is done by myself. As you can see, the contour is not closed. 
The desired output is something like:

[image]

So I need a function to close the outline/contour.  Who has a suggestion to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/O14tf.jpg"]
```

Using [`ImageMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageMesh.html) + [`BoundingRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundingRegion.html):

```
mindisk = BoundingRegion[ImageMesh[RemoveBackground@img], "MinDisk"]
```

> ```
> Disk[{56.0259, 59.0719}, 48.1942]
> ```

```
Show[img, Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], mindisk}]]
```

[image]